# VBA Excel. Como crear una función pero que no se vea en Excel

Tags: vba

Quiero crear una función en Excel desde vba. Cuando lo hago, desde cualquier celda es posible utilizarla como si fuera una función normal de Excel (*=Sum() por ejemplo*)

Pero yo no quiero este comportamiento!. Lo que deseo es crear una función en vba PERO que no sea visible desde la interface de Excel. La función **Private** no me sirve porque tengo varios módulos donde mando a llamar a esa función.
Tampoco quiero una subrutina (*sub*) ya que deseo la funcionalidad de poder compartir argumentos y variables, tal cual lo hace una función. Simplemente no deseo que esa función sea vista desde la interface de Excel.
Qué opciones sugieren? agradezco de antemano la atención recibida.

Answer (score 1):

No se puede hacer lo que quieres. Cualquier UDF que crees en VBA estará disponible para los usuarios. Si lo haces `Public` saldrá en el listado de funciones según escribes. Si es `Private` no saldrá el nombre, pero seguirá siendo accesible si el usuario escribe exactamente el nombre de la función.

Aunque lo consiguieras, piensa que si tú la usas, cualquier otro usuario podría mirar tu celda y ver lo que está escrito y por lo tanto, llamar a la función.

Tu única opción sería con un Sub que se ejecute desde macros.

Comment: Si, eso pensé... También utilicé las funciones dentro de Clases y funcionaron muy bien. Casi sin reprogramarlas...

Comment: @OswaldoFlores No tengo claro lo que quieres hacer, pero a lo mejor con los eventos de la clase Worksheet pudieras programar algo que ejecute una UDF privada, y así no tengas que poner nada en celdas. El usuario no vería el nombre de la función (seguiría pudiendo acceder si de alguna manera descubre el nombre exacto de la función).